# new event From Template does not copy custom fields

Tags: wordpress, civievent, custom-fields

On the demo site - http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/wp-admin/ I have created a new set of custom fields for Events - "Events custom fields" with one text field - "test1".
I have added value "tst" for this custom field in the event template "Free Meeting with Online Registration". [image]

When using this template on a new event the custom field value is not populated with what's in the template. Do I have to use hook to copy over custom data? If so what's the hook? [image]

[image]

Comment: Did you consider, or try, adding the default value in the custom field itself?

Comment: The default value in the custom field itself works on both event template and new event BUT this is not an option, you may have different values in the different templates and you want the value coming from the template.

Comment: Right, yes that makes sense.

Comment: It seems something civicrm does support just yet (i.e. hook has to be used to copy over custom data). If civicrm dev can confirm?

Comment: * does NOT support just yet

Comment: Previous versions of CiviCRM did copy over custom data fields. The custom data fields stopped being copied over from event templates in version 4.7.x or one version earlier. We have been hoping that this would be addressed in current version, but it appears that it has still has NOT been addressed in CiviCRM 5.4.0. We have confirmed that custom data fields values in event templates on our development site running Drupal 7.56 and CiviCRM 5.4.0 are NOT copied when creating an event from an event template.

Comment: I can confirm @509tyler's observations with Drupal 7.58 and Civi 5.3.1. Is there a road map for this feature returning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/766 this looks like it has now been fixed.

Comment: yes, I have tested it, it is fixed in the latest version.

Comment: Bug is back, see https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/event/-/issues/58